# Why create clk and clk NOT with 2 inverters instead of 1?

Tags: clock

I see many circuits use this topology
[image: Clock Generator]

Why dont we use just only one inverter like this:
[image: Inverter]

Thanks very much!

Comment: I think it has to do with the delay introduced by the inverter. The D-line gets slightly more time to settle with respect to CLK before its logic level is clocked into the flip flop. On top of that the clock pulse is being reshaped to a square, shaving off any ringing introduced by long leads.

Comment: I agree with Jippie. It's likely just introducing enough delay in the inverted buffer to allow more time for QM to setup and hold before being clocked in.

Comment: I think @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams has a valid point too.

Comment: I think this is a good question and does not deserve to be closed.

Comment: Even good questions deserve to be closed if they their answer has already been given on another question.

Comment: Sorry. I already searched, but maybe the key didnot match. I also dont want to spend time to ask another question where another similar question has been answered. Sorry again.

Comment: No worries. There are many ways of asking the same question, and it's impossible to search for all the possible ways of asking it.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I disagree that this is a duplicate, or rather that the linked question answer applies. In the link, the double inverter is used to buffer the input and reduce loading on the source. I believe in this case that it is done to provide an output transition on the positive clock edge.